# Delete white space on exact position in php

Tags: php, position, whitespace

I was just wondering how I could exactly remove white space or even character by row and position inside row. I can't find info about this but I think that the PHP `trim()` could  help. Also I was thinking about a solution for dynamic text. Where I want do delete all line's which are empty. Or just some of them.

### An example:

```
> here is text blabla
> 
> here is text balabla  balabala
> 
1
2 
3 
> oops too much space
> 
> also here is text
```

Now how can I strip the 3 white spaces away?

It has to become something like this:

```
> here is text blabla
> 
> here is text balabla  balabala
> 
> oops too much space
> 
> also here is text
```

Comment: `$text = preg_replace('~(\n|\r\n){3,}~', '\1\1', $text);`?

Comment: Are the `>` characters actually there btw?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems like you want regular expressions then:

```
preg_replace("#(\r?\n){3,}#", "\n\n", $str);
```

It replaces 3 newlines or more (i.e. two consecutive empty lines or more) with two newlines (one empty line).

To make sure it works with lines that only seem empty (i.e. a line with only spaces), you need to alter the expression slightly:

```
preg_replace("#(\r?\n\s*){3,}#", "\\1\\1", $str);
```

*Disclaimer: The `\\1\\1` idea came from NullPointerException :)*

You can also take a different route and solve it iteratively:

```
// $final is the result of the operation
// $n keeps track of how many empty lines were seen
$final = ''; $n = 0;
// $str is the original content, we split it into separate lines
foreach (preg_split("/\r?\n/", $str) as $line) {
        if (strlen(trim($line))) {
                $n = 0;
        } elseif (++$n >= 2) {
                continue;
        }
        // append to the final result
        $final .= "$line\n";
}
// rtrim($final, "\n");
```

Turns out that using `explode()` in the above iterative solution improves the performance; it still works with space-only lines because of `trim()`. However, you need to trim the newlines on the right side using `rtrim($final, "\n");`.

Comment: @NullUserException Haha figured you'd see that lol. I was distracted while I wrote the first pass.

Comment: can we haz an speedtest about what is faster?

Comment: @Jack I just did wrote a speedtest http://codepad.viper-7.com/o9jAch  mine is faster on codepad but yours is faster on my WAMP :O

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses The difference is mainly due to `explode()` vs `preg_replace()`. Both our iterative solutions don't return the same result as the `preg_replace()` though; yours adds a newline in front, mine one at the back :)

Comment: Works like a charm, you did it. Stil I am very confused by all the weird parameters inside the usage of preg_replace(). Maby I have to study them more!?

Comment: @Jack but why is explode faster on codepad and preg on WAMP :S

Answer (score 1):

not regex solution:

```
 function stripEmptyNewlines($string,$limit = 1){
     $array = explode("\n",$string);
     $emptyLine = 0;
     $newString = "";
     foreach($array as $child){
         if(trim($child) == "") {
             $emptyLine++;
         } else {
             $emptyLine = 0;
         }
         if($emptyLine < $limit + 1){
             $newString .= "\n" . $child;
         }
     }
     return $newString;
 }
```

Answer (score -1):

use the ReadLine() method on your text.

if ReadLine().Trim() != "", then add it to the output string. (else it will be an empty line)

Comment: @EaterOfCorpses its c# no php :) p.s. it=ans

Comment: This function you call readline is part of the gnu extension and is used for building a command line.